# $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$ is convergent.Is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}}{(i+1)a_{i+1}}$ divergent or not?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I think  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}}{(i+1)a_{i+1}}$ can be convergent.

My idea is to make $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}}{(i+1)a_{i+1}}$ alternating.So I tried the following series.
$$
a_{n}=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2k-1}&\text{n=4k-3}\\
\frac{-1}{2k-1}&\text{n=4k-2}\\
\frac{-1}{2k}&\text{n=4k-1}\\
\frac{1}{2k}&\text{n=4k}.
\end{cases}$$

$$\sum a_{n}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}-\cdots$$
The series is clearly convergent.

Then
$$
\frac{a_{n}}{(n+1)a_{n+1}}=\begin{cases}
\frac{-1}{(4k-2)}&\text{n=4k-3}\\
\frac{(2k)}{(4k-1)(2k-1)}&\text{n=4k-2}\\
\frac{-1}{(4k)}&\text{n=4k-1}\\
\frac{(2k+1)}{(4k+1)(2k)}&\text{n=4k}.
\end{cases}$$

In this way we can make $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}}{(i+1)a_{i+1}}$ an alternating series so it may be convergent.

But I cannot varify my example.
So is there other examples?Or is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}}{(i+1)a_{i+1}}$ just divergent?Any help will be thanked.

Comment: All finite sums are convergent. Do you mean $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty a_i$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \tfrac{a_i}{(i+1)a_{i+1}}$? And what if your original sum is finite, i.e. $a_i = 0$ for $i > N$? Then your second sum isn't defined.

Comment: I think he's asking if the second series can be convergent? But isn't it possible when $a$ is exponentially growing? Edit: Wait no, then the first series will not be convergent.

Comment: Let $a_i = 1/2^i$. Then the first series converges but the second one doesnt.

Comment: Yes, so it "usually" diverges, and he's asking if both of them can be convergent. It's answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b_i = (-1)^i/\sqrt{i}$ for $i \geq 1$ and define

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n! b_1 \cdots b_{n-1}}. $$

Here, the empty product arising when $n = 1$ is considered as $1$ so that $a_1 = 1$. Then we easily check that

- $\displaystyle |a_n| = \frac{1}{n \sqrt{(n-1)!}}$ is absolutely summable by the ratio test.
- $\displaystyle \frac{a_n}{(n+1)a_{n+1}} = b_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} $ is conditionally summable by the alternating series test.

Therefore both

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(n+1)a_{n+1}} $$

converge.